# Two or more html form on same php page performing different tasks

Tags: php, html

I have two or more HTML form on same page performing different tasks, how can i differentiate that which one is to be called on button click in Php. or do i need to use functions?

Comment: describe your question in detail. what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Do they post to the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use different name attribute for submit button for each form and in php use `if($_POST['submit1'] == 'submit1')` for first form's submit button click for second one `if($_POST['submit2'] == 'submit2')` if you are using `post` action.

Comment: I need a code for a web form with buttons add, find, delete and edit.

Comment: I need a code for a web form with buttons add, find, delete and edit. with two text fields i.e name and link.
criteria is when user open the form, by default it is not editable and user will not be able to write in the fields unless he/she press any of the above button. now on button click I need to change form controls like if the user click on add button it makes form editable and shows buttons save, cancel and exit instead of edit, find and delete.

Comment: oh thats the bad thing you tell me.. I hate jquery its always Fu***** to me.

Comment: any other possibility to do this using just HTML and Php.

Comment: other option is present but it will refresh the web page and you have to code more to store the clicked button name and other information.

Comment: `jquery` is big thing to learn. I will advice you to search on google for basic tutorial and start from that.

Comment: okay. with depth of my heart thanks very much for the help and your time. Stay blessed

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_1'])){do this}
elseif(isset($_POST['submit_2'])){do that}
else{ echo 'form data';}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:

```
<form name="Form1" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ]; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="Form1">
  <input class="button-primary" name="Submit1" type="submit" value="" />
</form>

<form name="Form2" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ]; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="Form2">
  <input class="button-primary" name="Submit2" type="submit" value="" />
</form>

<?php
if ( $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] == 'POST' ) {
  if ( isset ( $_POST[ 'Submit1' ] ) ) {
    // Get Form1
  }

  if ( isset ( $_POST[ 'Submit2' ] ) ) {
    // Get Form2
  }

}

?>
```

Comment: ok i got this but can u please tell me what is the function of **$_SERVER** here?

Comment: To redirect the page to itself after the form is submitted as HTML and PHP are in the same script. But that is just an example, is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GET variables to pass through the form.

On your first form, you can set the form `action` to `processingPage.php?form=1`. And the second form can be `processingPage.php?form=2`

Then, in php, you can just do

```
if($_GET['form'] == "1")
{
FORM 1 STUFF HERE
}
else if($_GET['form'] == "2")
{
FORM 2 STUFF HERE
}
```